# How can I make the screenshot Prompt to provide me with the option to select a region?

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Right now, when I press the <kbd>prtsc</kbd> button, I recieve the following prompt:

[image: Screenshot 1]

But instead I want to get to this prompt when I press the <kbd>prtsc</kbd> button:

[image: Screenshot 2]

I can only get the second prompt if I click screenshot through the menu:

[image: Menu]

<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>prtsc</kbd> does not give me any prompt, and no other combination of keys gives me the second prompt. How can I get the second prompt using a key combo? Is there somewhere where I can define such a combo?

Or does one already exist which I was not aware of? I am using Xubuntu-Desktop if that helps. I specifically want the prompt in the second screenshot, NOT the one shown here:

[image: here]

Which is a completely different prompt that is less user-friendly in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The program you are looking for is `xfce4-screenshooter` Go to **System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts**. You can add your custom combination there. For the command you want to execute by pressing your special combination enter

```
xfce4-screenshooter
```

**Tip:** When you have your screenshot application shown on screen try `ps ax` and you can see, which application is actually running. I am pretty sure it is `xfce4-screenshooter`.

Comment: this worked, I bound it to shift+prtsc

thank you very much